# relation between 2 series

Tags: sequences-and-series, laplace-transform

imagine we get $ f(x)= \sum_{n=0}^{\infty}a(n)x^{n} $

and  $ g(x)= \sum_{n=0}^{\infty}\frac{a(n)}{n!}x^{n} $

then if i know $ g(x)$ i can get $ f(x) $ using laplace transform but what if i know only the value of $ f(x) $ ??

Comment: **Hint :** $$a_n = \dfrac{f^{(n)}(0)}{n!}$$

Comment: If you can go from $g(x)$ to $f(x)$ through the Laplace transform,
$$ f(x) = \int_{0}^{+\infty} g(xt) e^{-t}\,dt \tag{1}$$
you can go from $f(x)$ to $g(x)$ through the *inverse* Laplace transform.<br>  $\frac{1}{n!}$ is the coefficient of $u^n$ in the Maclaurin series of $e^u$, so

$$ \frac{1}{n!} = \frac{1}{2\pi i}\oint_{|u|=1}\frac{e^u}{u^{n+1}}\,du $$
and 
$$ g(x) = \frac{1}{2\pi i}\oint_{|u|=1} f(x/u)\frac{e^u}{u}\,du. \tag{2}$$

Comment: Of course you need some information about the rate of growth of the sequence $\{a_n\}_{n\geq 0}$ in order to ensure that such transform / inverse transform actually make sense.